# Should a sidebar containing options or properties be placed on the left or right in an app?

Tags: consistency, sidebar, mobile-application

I'm writing a tasks app for Ubuntu Touch. In the home page, I have a list of projects in a sidebar on the left, with a list of tasks on the right:

[image: Home page]

When a user clicks a task, he is taken to a page showing details about the task, such as title, description, due date, etc:

[image: Task view page]

I originally put the sidebar there on the right to focus the user on the parts of the task need to complete it, namely, title, description, and checklist, and because I think of putting a sidebar containing options/properties on the right.

Is this a good idea, or is it better to put it on the left to be consistent with the rest of the app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first screenshot shows navigational items, and is placed to the left because of English reading order, left-to-right (LTR). This means that items to the left are higher up in the hierarchy than items to the right. Works perfectly.

The second sceenshot shows option menu (not for navigation) to the right of the main item. These options are attributes of the main item. Not really a hierarchy, but one of several attributes, together making an instance of the whole item.

These two screenshots are different things so you don't have to be consistent. In fact, I think your current setup is very logical and well thought through.